# how do i use permission overwrites discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

it worked on my last bot but now the permission overwrites wont work on the new bot i looked at documentation on discord.js was just wandering if someone could help me out as im at a dead end

code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ticket',
    description: "creates ticket",
    async execute(message, args, Discord){
        const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.author.tag}`);
        channel.setParent('967965866035642408');

        channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.guild.id, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
        });
        channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.author, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
        });

        const reactionMessage = await channel.send('Thank you for contacting support!');

        try{

            await reactionMessage.react("");
            await reactionMessage.react("⛔");

        }catch(err){
            channel.send('Error sending emojis!');
            throw err;
        }
        const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
            (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"),
            {dispose: true }
        );

        collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case "":
                    channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
                    break;
                case "⛔":
                    channel.send('deleting this channel in 5 seconds');
                    setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
                    break;
            }
        });

        message.channel.send(`we will be right with you! ${channel}`).then((msg) => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
            setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
        }).catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: also lock and delete emoji doesnt work bit confused on that as well any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So the first part of this would be the command, and I seperated the command from the reaction, just in case the bot reboots or there was ever an error with the collector, this code will survive a reboot. I also tested this on my bot and it works without issue.

Command.js file

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ticket',
    description: "creates ticket",
    async execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.author.tag}`, {
            parent: '967965866035642408',
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                id: message.guild.id,
                deny: [
                    'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                ],
            }, {
                id: message.author,
                allow: [
                    'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                    'SEND_MESSAGES',
                ],
            }],
        });

        const reactionMessage = await channel.send(`Thank you for contacting support! ${message.author}`);
        // message.author is important for later so make sure it stays in the message somehow.

        try {
            await reactionMessage.react("");
            await reactionMessage.react("⛔");

        } catch (err) {
            channel.send('Error sending emojis!');
            throw err;
        }

        message.channel.send(`we will be right with you! ${channel}`).then((msg) => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
            setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
        }).catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });
    },
};
```

This section would go into your main bot.js file to catch the reaction add and it will auto remove reactions that are placed by members who are not admins

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (messageReaction, user) => {
    if (user.bot) return;
    const message = await messageReaction.message.fetch(true);
    const channel = message.channel;
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guildId);
    const member = guild.members.cache.get(user.id);

    if (channel.parent.id === '967965866035642408') {
        const regex = /\d+/g;
        const authorID = message.content.match(regex);
        const originalAuthor = client.users.cache.get(authorID[0]);
        if (!member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            message.reactions.cache.find(reaction => reaction.emoji.name == messageReaction.emoji.name).users.remove(member.user);
            return;
        } else {
            switch (messageReaction.emoji.name) {
            case "":
                channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(originalAuthor, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
                break;
            case "⛔":
                channel.send('deleting this channel in 5 seconds');
                setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```